# unhandled exception, invalid parameter passed to a function that considers invalid paramaters fatal

Tags: c++, exception, breakpoints

I'm using visual studio 2017, and coding under unreal engine coding standards, and its throwing an unhandled exception with invalid parameters passed to a function that considers them fatal. I can't figure it out, the VS2017 debugger is completely useless, and I'm pretty new to coding, can anyone throw me some suggestions? EDIT: The only thing that i can come close to finding is that it appears to be being cause by a string being out of range cause by an infinite loop somewhere in the function below.

```
FBullCowCount FBullCowGame::SubmitGuess(FText Guess)
{
// increment the turn number
MyCurrentTry++;

// setup a return variable
FBullCowCount BullCowCount;

// loop through all letters in the guess
int32 HiddenWordLength = MyHiddenWord.length();
for (int32 MHWChar = 0; MHWChar < HiddenWordLength; MHWChar++) {

    // compare letters against the hidden word
    for (int32 GChar = 0; GChar < HiddenWordLength; GChar++) {

        //if they match then
        if (Guess[MHWChar] == MyHiddenWord[MHWChar])
        {
            //increment bulls if they're in the same place
            if (MHWChar == GChar) {
                BullCowCount.Bulls++;
            }
                else {
                    BullCowCount.Cows++;
                }
        }
    }   //increment cows if not
}
return BullCowCount;
}
```

Comment: Are we supposed to to guess what is the problematic call? Put yourselves in our shoes. Imagine you've never seen your entire codebase.  Imagine you are presented only with this. Could you figure out what's the problem?

Comment: "Throwing suggestions" is not how this site works. You are supposed to make a [mcve] that allows everyone to reproduce the error and verify that their solution solves the problem.

Comment: idk, I just need more brains than my own, this code block is fairly independant and the breakpoint is happening wholly within this function as far as i can see. I guess the main thing i want to know is can anyone see any major flaws with the way i have written any of the loops.

Comment: i can throw my entire code up on github if you want

Comment: That's not how debugging works. VisualStudio should be pointing out the exact line and function call that is throwing. Also it should be breaking (freezing but not terminating) your program so that you can actually look up the values of the variables that cause the function to throw. If you still can't figure out what's wrong after reading that info, edit your post to include them so that we can try to figure it out.

Comment: its not telling me though, VS itself doesnt know exactly what the problem is, just what kind of a problem it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code comment says "loop through all letters in the guess", but your code loops through all letters of `MyHiddenWord` instead. That means that unless both `Guess` and `MyHiddenWord` have the exact same length, this:

```
if (Guess[MHWChar] == MyHiddenWord[MHWChar])
```

will at some point access an element of `Guess` that's out of range, and this is the likely cause of the exception, if `FText` happens to use a range-checked `operator[]`.

What you probably want here is:

```
#include <algorithm>
// ...

auto HiddenWordLength = std::min(MyHiddenWord.length(), Guess.length());
```

It will limit the amount of letters to loop through to the shorter of the two strings.

Comment: Oh right let me see if i can try and define the length of Guess because technically its length right now is set as FText Guess = ""; which then grabs the users input for the length.

Comment: ok your solution worked perfectly, thank you very much